# TFS 2013 Not Restoring NuGet Packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, nuget, nuget-package-restore

According to the [NuGet Documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build), NuGet package restore should "just work" with TFS 2013.

It's not.

When the build machine runs, it gives me the following error (where it can't find Newtonsoft.Json)

```
Program.cs (5): The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is with a brand new project, on TFS 2013 using the default template(TfvcTemplate.12.xaml). I'm using VS 2013. Honestly, I'm new to TFS so I'm not sure what a build log *should* look like, but mine looks like this:

```
Overall Build Process
Overall build process
Update build number
Run on agent (reserved build agent CTIDEV2k8 - Agent1)
Initialize environment
Get sources from Team Foundation Version Control
Associate the changesets that occurred since the last good build
Compile, Test and Publish
Run optional script before MSBuild
Run MSBuild
Built $/Web/TestApp/TestApp.sln for default targets.
Built $/Web/TestApp/TestApp/TestApp.csproj for default targets.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (1697): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
Program.cs (5): The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
MSBuild Log File
Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
Handle Exception
Create a bug for the build failure
Rethrow the exception so the build will stop
Perform Final Actions On Agent
Copy binaries to drop
Reset the Environment
Work item '96: Build Failure in Build: TestApp2_20150224.2' was opened by the build.
```

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Is this on the build machine? If so, do you have Visual Studio installed on that machine?

Comment: @BuckHodges: Yes and yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that we had an internal Nuget package feed. The issue was fixed by adding a nuget.config file to the root of the solution folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="InternalFeed" value="https://our.nuget.com" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your response helped me feel better, getting 'Build succeeded' after a whole day of struggle. Thanks & cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Package Restore is enabled in the Visual Studio on your Build Server? The Build Server can reach nuget.org? You can open the TestApp.sln on your Build Server and try to compile this manually. Does this work?

[image: Enable Package Restore]

Comment: Yes, restore is enabled on the server, and when opening the solution in VS on the server, it restores the package and compiles.